# with-pattern result not visible

Tags: agda

I am trying to see how to branch into "safely-typed" code. For example, below is meant to call `tail` only on the safe path - i.e. if the list on input is non-empty. There would be an easy way, of course, to just pattern-match the list, but the idea is to reconcile the result of a function (`null`) and its use on the right-hand side:

```
data Void : Set where

data _==_ {A : Set} (x : A) : A -> Set where
  refl : x == x

data Bool : Set where
  True : Bool
  False : Bool

data List (A : Set) : Set where
  nil  : List A
  _::_ : A -> List A -> List A

null : forall {A} -> List A -> Bool
null nil         = True
null (x :: xs)   = False

non-null : forall {A} -> List A -> Set
non-null nil = Void
non-null (x :: xs) = (x :: xs) == (x :: xs)

tail : forall {A} -> (xs : List A) -> {p : non-null xs} -> List A
tail (_ :: xs) = xs
tail nil      {p = ()}

prove-non-null : forall {A} -> (xs : List A) -> (null xs == False) -> non-null xs
prove-non-null nil         ()
prove-non-null (x :: xs)   refl = refl

compileme : forall {A} -> List A -> List A
compileme xs with null xs
...             | True    = xs
...             | False   = tail xs {prove-non-null xs refl}
```

On the last line agda complains that `refl` cannot be proven to be of type `null xs == False`. Why can't it see with-clause has just witnessed `null xs` is `False`?

What's the right way about it? How to "extract" the dependency from a seemingly non-dependent results, like `Bool` type is not dependent on the list `xs`, but in the context it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's about the `inspect` idiom. Check [the original thread](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2011/003286.html) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667359/agda-type-of-proofs-and-with-clause). [The current version](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.html#5150) of `inspect` in the standard library is from [this](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2014/007325.html) thread (there are also some [explanations](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2014/007330.html)).

If you delete the definition of `_==_`, then you can define `compileme` as

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality renaming (_≡_ to _==_)

...

compileme : forall {A} -> List A -> List A
compileme xs with null xs | inspect null xs
...             | True    | [ _ ] = xs
...             | False   | [ p ] = tail xs {prove-non-null xs p}
```

BTW, what is `(x :: xs) == (x :: xs)` supposed to mean? It's just

```
open import Data.Unit
...
non-null (x :: xs) = ⊤
```

BTW2, you can define type-safe `tail` as I defined type-safe `pred` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28589398/3237465) answer.

Comment: well, at first `non-null` was meant to somehow express a type `(x :: xs) == ys`, if `ys` is non-null, but then I reduced the requirements, which made it look silly.